# inserting data into mysql database using nodejs angularjs

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am newbie. i am not able to insert data from front end into mysql database.
I am facing the problem at the time of insertion. I'm unable to trace my coding error whether it is in **controller.js** or in **index.html** or in **server.js**.
Please help me to solve this.

**my server.js code**

```
var express    = require("express");
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
   host     : 'localhost',
   user     : 'root',
   password : '',
   database : 'bookitnow'
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
   if (!err)
     console.log('Database is connected');
   else
     console.log('DB connection error.');
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/index.html', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public' + 'index.html');
});


app.post('/index.html', function(req, res, next) {
  var data = req.body;
    console.log('request received:', data);

    connection.query('INSERT INTO register SET ?', data, function(err,res){
      if(err) throw err;
        console.log('record inserted');
    });  

app.listen(5500);

console.log('Hi from server.js');
```

**my controller.js code**

```
 var app = angular.module('bookitnow',[]);
        app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope,$http){
        $scope.submit = function() {

            var data = {
                    fName   : $scope.fname, 
                    lName   : $scope.lname,
                    email   : $scope.email,
                    phone   : $scope.phone,
                    password: $scope.pswd,
                    confirm : $scope.confirm
                }   
            };

            $http.post('/index.html', &scope.data)
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    $scope.result = data;
                    console.log("inserted successfully")
                })
                .error(function(data, status, header, config){
                    $scope.result = "Data: " + status;


                });

            $scope.add.push(data);
            $scope.addNewUser = {
                    fname:"",
                    lname:"",
                    email:"",
                    phone:"",
                    password:"",
                    confirm:""
        };
});
```

**my index.html code**

```
<html ng-app="bookitnow">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">

    <title> Registration Page </title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container" ng-app="bookitnow" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <h1>Register</h1>
    <form method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" ng-model="fname" placeholder="First Name" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" ng-model="lname" placeholder="Last Name" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" ng-model="email" placeholder="Email Address" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" ng-model="phone" placeholder="Phone" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pswd" ng-model="pswd" placeholder="Password" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="confirm" ng-model="confirm" placeholder="Confirm Password" required>
    </div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" ng-click="submit()">Submit</button>

</form>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="controllers/controller.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the error? can you post here?

Comment: Browser responding the message: cannot POST /

Answer (score 1):

Your route is not proper.

This is not a valid route

```
app.get('/index.html')
```

Change your all route in on server side like this

```
 app.get('/', function(req, res) {//remove index.html
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public' + 'index.html');
});


app.post('/', function(req, res, next) {//remove index.html
      var data = req.body;
      console.log('request received:', data);

      connection.query('INSERT INTO register SET ?', data, function(err, res) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('record inserted');
      });
```

And request from client side like this

```
 $http.post('/', $scope.data)
   .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
     $scope.result = data;
     console.log("inserted successfully")
   })
   .error(function(data, status, header, config) {
     $scope.result = "Data: " + status;
   });
```

Hope this will work for you

Comment: You've mentioned $http.post('/', & scope.data).

Comment: I just changed your route buddy you can check rest of code

Comment: ERROR:       angular.js:12011POST http://localhost:5500/ 404 (Not Found)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:12011n @ angular.js:11776(anonymous function) @ angular.js:11571(anonymous function) @ angular.js:16383$eval @ angular.js:17682$digest @ angular.js:17495$apply @ angular.js:17790(anonymous function) @ angular.js:1761invoke @ angular.js:4718c @ angular.js:1759Bc @ angular.js:1779fe @ angular.js:1664(anonymous function) @ angular.js:31763b @ angular.js:3207Sf @ angular.js:3497d @ angular.js:3485

Comment: Match your requested URL with server URL. something is mismatching